# Undiagnosed Tweepy Tweet Output Error - Program working but no output

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

My Tweepy is giving an output as tweeting but there is no tweet. What am I missing?
Using Python 3.11, Pycharm Community version.

Testing the bot as of now. Not getting any errors. Can't seem to dianose the errors since the code if compiling correctly.

I have pasted the code below:-

`

```
import tweepy
import configparser
import os
import threading
import time
import sys

WAIT_TIME = 300000
done = False

def get_tokens():
    api_key = 'key'
    api_secret_key = 'key secret'
    access_token_key = 'token key'
    access_token_secret = 'token secret'
    return api_key, api_secret_key, access_token_key, access_token_secret


def animate():
    for c in range(WAIT_TIME, -1, -1):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rWaiting for ' + str(c) + ' secs.... ')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write('\rTweeting\n')


def write_tweeted_img(file_name):
    file = open(r"new.txt", 'a') #file path
    file.write('{}\n'.format(file_name))
    file.close()


def check_img_tweeted(file_name):
    with open(r"new.txt") as f: #file path
        if file_name in f.read():
            return True
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret = get_tokens()
    count = 0

    print('Connecting to Twitter...')
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print('Connected!\n')

    os.chdir(r"") #imge directory path
    for image in os.listdir(r""): #imge directory path

        if check_img_tweeted(image):
            print('Already Tweeted {} before'.format(image))
            os.remove(image)
            continue

        try:
            api.search_tweets(image)
            print('Tweeted {}'.format(image))
            write_tweeted_img(image)
            count += 1
            os.remove(image)
            done = False

        except TweepError:
            continue

        t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(WAIT_TIME)
        done = True

    print('\nSuccessfully Tweeted {} Images'.format(count))`
```

Pycharm is not giving any error.Output is -

Connecting to Twitter...
Connected!

Tweeted Slide1.JPG
Waiting for XYZ secs....

Tried Anaconda and python 3.7 as interpreter as well(after requisite modifications). Same output. Presently using Python 3.11 as interpreter.